# redirecting output from several piped commands

Tags: bash, redirection, pipe

This works:

```
find . -type f | xargs md5sum | sort
```

This does not and gives several "md5sum: xyz not found" errors:

```
( find . -type f | xargs md5sum | sort ) >~/md5.txt
```

Same for:

```
find . -type f | xargs md5sum | sort >~/md5.txt
```

This works:

```
md5deep -r . | sort >~/md5.txt
```

I would like to understand why the redirection of the pipe constructs doesn't work.

Comment: Your third example produces valid output for me. What operating system are you testing on?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS + bash version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very possibly, file name starts with `xyz` contains `white space`.
You can try this:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort
```

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. Should have noticed that. Thanks. :)